# Loader method unloadAndStop() behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

Had some issues using the loader and I feel I need to totally understand how the unloadAndStop() method works. I'm working on a project that loads in multiple swfs when required at runtime. For this I've been using a single loader and pulling out its contents to a cache when it's complete.

The single loader is implemented via an extended class that I haven't written, and it seems to implement the "unloadAndStop(true) method when loading in a new URLRequest.

Now, I've had some strange issues using this system, and I've traced it back to the unloadAndStop(true) call, which according to the Adobe documentation stops audio, playback, and flags for removal by the garbage collector. Obviously this isn't what I want; I still have references to this object on the stage and in my cache! It seems strange to me that there's a way to flag something directly for garbage collection in this manner, where, as far as I know, there's no other way to do that.

So that causes me to assume that in order to properly remove something loaded with a loader you *have* to unload it in the manner. Is this the case? If I load something in, pull out its contents to movieClip1, load in a new movieClip, and then remove all references to movieClip1 (the original Loader contents) will that be garbage collected, or does it have to be removed via the unloadAndStop method?

TL;DR:

Is it necessary to call unloadAndStop(true) from a loader to guarentee anything it has loaded gets removed from memory, or can the loader load another URLRequest without fear of a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well described in the docs:

gc:Boolean (default = true) — Provides a hint to the garbage collector to run on the child SWF objects (true) or not (false). If you are unloading many objects asynchronously, setting the gc paramter to false might improve application performance. However, if the parameter is set to false, media and display objects of the child SWF file might persist in memory after running the unloadAndStop() command.

It's because you can have some SWF, get some specific child, and remove the SWF. But you keep reference to it's child, which means that the child won't be garbage collected. But if you force GC to check children, it will try to mark all of them for collection, and leave the ones that are used.

So basically, there is no need to force GC in order to clean things out. The best and most important practice is to remove everything from Stage, and clean all references to it. It will sooner or later going to be checked by GC. `unloadAndStop` is a shortcut for someone that doesn't keep track on what he's doing and just a safety measure to be sure that you've cleaned as much as you can.

I personally don't use it.